# Norm of differentiation operator $Tf(t)=f'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Consider $T:C^1([0, 1])\to C([0, 1])$ given by $Tf=f'$ where $$\|f\|_{C^1}=\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$$ and $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in [0, 1]}|f(x)|$. How to prove $\|T\|=1$? The inequality $\|T\|\leq 1$ is easy, but I can't find a function for showing this upper bound is achieved.

Comment: how can we show above equality ||f||₁=||f′||_{∞}+||f||_{∞}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the functions
$$
f_n(x)=x^n
$$
for $n\geq 1$.
Then 
$$
\|f_n\|_{C^1}=\|x^n\|_\infty+\|nx^{n-1}\|_\infty =n+1
$$
and 
$$
\|Tf_n\|_\infty=\|nx^{n-1}\|_\infty=n.
$$
So 
$$
\|T\|\geq \frac{n}{n+1}
$$
for all $n$.

Hence $\|T\|\geq 1$ when letting $n$ tend to $\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh! Thanks! What a trick.

Comment: Nice Proof, thanks =D

Answer (score 3):

No function can realize the upper bound.

However, we can approach it by functions like $f_n(x):=\frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}n$.

Comment: I was almost sure that approximation would be needed...Thanks for the tip..